# Auto generate PlantUml Class Diagrams C# Code

Tags: c#, diagram

Looking for software/extension/nuget package recommendations to easily generate PlantUml Diagrams. More specifically for class diagram with C#. I know there are a few out there, but they all require .net core or .net 4.5+. The main base of our code is older than this and struggling to find something that would work.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at https://github.com/pierre3/PlantUmlClassDiagramGenerator It can be run standalone.  It looks at your source file and generates rudimentary class diagrams.

Might be worth a look.